# Manipulation of imported Datafile

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, import, data-structures

Since I am solving a differential equation in a *for loop* with NDSolve

```
For[i = 1, i < 100, i = i + 0.02, 
 With[{epsilon = 10^(-4), epsilonv = 10^(-3), epsilonphi = 0.01*i}, 
  s = NDSolve[{y''[
        x] + (1 + 1/(epsilonv*x)*Exp[-epsilonphi*x/(epsilonv)])*
        y[x] == 0, y[epsilon] == epsilon, y'[epsilon] == 1}, 
    y, {x, 0, 40}, MaxSteps -> 1000]]; 
 WriteString[
  "/path/data.dat", {0.01*i, 
   Evaluate[1/((y[30]^2 + y[30 - Pi/2]^2)) /. s]  "\n"} ]]
```

and write a specific result for each round into a data, I get a data which looks like

> {0.01, {7950.27 }} {0.0102, {3401.31 }} {0.0104, {1699.61 }} {0.0106,
>   {1061.8 }}  .......

But if I want to plot this data like

```
data = Import["/path/data.dat", "Table"];
numeric = ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",  PlotRange -> {{0.01, 1}, {1, 10^7}}]
```

I get a plot like this:

[image]

While I get the following plot with the same code if I replace all "{" , "}" , "," in the data file with a blank space:

[image]

So my question is: How can the data file be manipulated while importing to delete all "{" , "}" , ","  or at least to plot it without deleting these symbold "by hand" in the data itself.

Comment: use `/. First@s` when you write the data then you wont have the extra curlies to begin with.   If you are stuck with the data like that do `Flatten/@data`

Comment: aside to your question your code throws a bunch of errors that should not be ignored.

Comment: @george2079 Well, the errors can be safely ignored since the output fits well with a given analytical approximation. But alas your suggestions couldnt solve the problem or I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WriteString` in your loop form should be:

```
 WriteString[path, 0.01*i, " ", 
       1/((y[30]^2 + y[30 - Pi/2]^2)) /. First@s, "\n"]
```

This gives you *no* `{ }` in the file and `Imports` properly. 
You could also use `Write`:

```
  Write[path, 0.01*i, OutputForm[" "], 
       1/((y[30]^2 + y[30 - Pi/2]^2)) /. First@s]
```

That said its usually preferable to generate all the data and write with a single `Export`:

```
data = Table[{i, 
   1/((y[30]^2 + y[30 - Pi/2]^2)) /. 
    With[{epsilon = 10^(-4), epsilonv = 10^(-3), 
       epsilonphi = 0.01*i}, 
         First@NDSolve[{y''[x] +
           (1 + 1/(epsilonv*x)*Exp[-epsilonphi*x/(epsilonv)])*
            y[x] == 0, y[epsilon] == epsilon, y'[epsilon] == 1}, 
        y, {x, 0, 40}, MaxSteps -> 1000]]}, {i, 1, 100, .02}];
Export[path, data]
```

Comment: Thanks @george2079, both suggestions works fine! 
But in the latter case: is it possible to get in some sense an adaptive step size, e.g. i = i + i/(100) ? Because if I insert  {i, 1, 100, i/(100)} I get some errors which cant be ignored

Comment: if you want log scaling let the table index run from say `{i,-2,0,.1}` and let `epsilonphi=10^i`.